# Первый символ строки

Tags: php, строки

**Предыстория:**

В базе хранится полное ФИО.

**Задача**

Необходимо вывести "Фамилия И.О."

**Проблема**

Строка хранится в юникоде, и чтобы получить 1-ый символ строки на Русском мне надо брать первые 2 символа `substr($nam, 0, 2)`, но если в строке Английские буквы, то выдаст 2 символа. *Как лучше решить данную проблему?*

Comment: `mb_substr()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не успел, mb_substr. Но лучше в данной ситуации хранить ФИО в 3 столбцах.

Comment: поторопился с выбором ответа ) mb_substr($nam, 0, 1) то же вернуло не то что хотелось... щас посмотрю на счет параметра **encoding**

Comment: да, спасибо за ответ :)

        `mb_substr($name,0,1,"UTF-8")`

Comment: Да глупости это - руками делать то, что изначально поддерживается в БД...

Answer (score 8):

```
select substr(name,1,1) from table
```

Comment: как вариант ) но меня больше интересует обработка в php, т.е. после запроса мне необходимы как сокращенные имена так и полные.

Comment: select substr(name,1,1) as name1, name as name2...